# :checked pseudo class does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-selectors

I'm creating a custom checkbox with this css:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: transparent;
    border: inherit;
    width: auto;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + input + label,
input[type=checkbox] + label,
div:not(#foo) > input[type=checkbox] + label,
div:not(#foo) > input[type=checkbox] + input + label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 0 0 0 18px;
    background: transparent url(/assets/images/checkbox-unchecked.png) no-repeat left 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + input + label,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label,
div:not(#foo) > input[type=checkbox]:checked + label,
div:not(#foo) > input[type=checkbox]:checked + input + label {
    background: transparent url(/assets/images/checkbox-checked.png) no-repeat left 3px;
}
.ie6 input[type=checkbox],
.ie7 input[type=checkbox],
.ie8 input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

and here is my html markup:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <input class="check-box" data-val="true" id="Persistent" name="Persistent" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <input name="Persistent" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <label for="Persistent">Keep me!</label>
</div>
```

The `input` elements are created by `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BooleanProp)` in `Razor`. This code works fine except in Chrome. Actually in Chrome, when we click on checkbox, we will see the effect (by effect I mean changing the background-image for label that shows checkbox is checked or not) after we click on submit bottun. Any idea please?

**UPDATE**

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dLSPJ/4/)

Comment: Do you have a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could see that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that Webkit has issues with chained `+` selectors that follow pseudo selectors

Swap the chained  `... + input + label` selectors for `... ~ label`.

For example:

```
div:not(#foo) > input[type=checkbox] ~ label
```

Comment: @Mak that is not really a useful comment. Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating this not working